# How to temporarily disable user interaction from all textfields if one is being edited?

Tags: ios, swift, input

Is there a way to temporarily disable the interaction and input for all textfields on a ViewController if one is currently being edited. After keyboard or UIPicker disapears, I would like the textField interaction to be enabled again.

I understand to disable touch interaction I can use:

`textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

But what if I also have `textField2` and `textField3` how can I **temporarily** disable user interaction of both textFields when I am editing `textfield1` ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Ideal scenario would be to handle users tapping on other textFields using the `textDidBeginEditing` and `textDidEndEditing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create outlet collection for all the textfields like

```
@IBOutlet var textFs:[UITextField]!
```

Then set the vc as the delegate for all of them in `viewDidLoad`

```
textFs.forEach { $0.delegate = self }
```

Implement

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) { 
   textFs.forEach {
     if $0 != textField {
       $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
  }
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
   textFs.forEach {  $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = true }
}
```

Comment: I get the error, Value of type 'UITextField?' has no member 'forEach'

Comment: `textFs` should be an array `textFs:[UITextField]! ` and connect all textfields in IB to it

Comment: I have created the collection, mine does not include weak,  @IBOutlet var textFs: [UITextField]!

Comment: what's the current problem